# Jquery 'mouseenter' doing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is the jquery

```
jQuery(document).on("ready page:load", function() {

var img = $('.img-profile')
var layer = $('.project-layer1')

layer.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).animate({'transform' : 'scale(0.8)'}, 'slow');
});
layer.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).animate({'transform' : 'scale(1)' }, 1000);
});
});
```

This is the html

```
<div class="project-list">
<div class="project-list-container">
    <div class="project-layer1">
        <div class="project-desc">Tutor U</div>
        <div class="project-logo">
            <%= image_tag "233HHH.jpg", class: 'img-profile' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's in rails hence the image_tag.. but I don't understand why nothing is happening when mouse hovers over.

Comment: no error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is not a property that can be animated using jQuery.

You can use [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to set the animation properties like

```js
jQuery(document).on("ready page:load", function() {

  var img = $('.img-profile')
  var layer = $('.project-layer1')

  layer.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'transform': 'scale(0.8)'
    });
  });
  layer.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'transform': 'scale(1)'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.project-layer1 {
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-list">
  <div class="project-list-container">
    <div class="project-layer1">
      <div class="project-desc">Tutor U</div>
      <div class="project-logo">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

There is no need to use scripting for this effect, you can just use the `:hover` css rule

```js
jQuery(document).on("ready page:load", function() {

  var img = $('.img-profile')
  var layer = $('.project-layer1')

});
```

```css
.project-layer1 {
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
.project-layer1:hover {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-list">
  <div class="project-list-container">
    <div class="project-layer1">
      <div class="project-desc">Tutor U</div>
      <div class="project-logo">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have used 'transform' property previously and that was working. May be I am not totally remembering.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal the animate function works with css rules which has numerical values, since in this case `scale` is used I don't think there is a direct solution, there might be workarounds, but I'm not aware of them

Comment: @BhojendraNepal the animate function has a custom `step` value which can be used to give the animation I think